# Срабатывает условие просто так python

Tags: python

Начал сегодня учить Python, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
Не срабатывает ни одно из условий

```
import random
money = 1000
while money > 0:
        s = int(input("Ставка:"))
        money -= s
        r = random.randint(0, 14)
        print(r)
        v = int(input("1 - красное \n 2 - черное \n 3 - зеро"))
        if v == 3 and r == 0:
            print("Ставка выиграла")
            money += s*5
            print("Ваш баланс: "+ str(money))
            print("1")
        else:
            if v == 2 and (r > 0 and r < 8):
                print("Ставка выиграла")
                money += s*2
                print("Ваш баланс: "+ str(money))
                print("1")
            else:
                if v == 1 and r > 8:
                    print("Ставка выиграла")
                    money += s*2
                    print("Ваш баланс: "+ str(money))
                    print("1")
```

Comment: `input` строку возвращает

Comment: @КириллВеликий, что значит "просто так"?

Comment: Ну по условиям же должно выполняться 1 из 3х условий, иначе не выполняется ничего. А у меня почему то выполняется, когда не должно. Или я что то путаю???

Comment: Что должно произойти, если v равно 3, а r равно 2?

Comment: Ничего. Такого условия же нету

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Во-первых**, здесь есть реакция только на "выигрышные" комбинации.

**Во-вторых**, стоит проверить отступы.

**Во-третьих**, зачем-то использованы вложенные if. *Don't repeat yourself!*

Вот возможный вариант написания.

```
if  (v == 3 and r == 0): 
    print("Ставка выиграла")
    money += s*5
elif (v == 2 and (r > 0 and r < 8) or v == 1 and r > 8):
    print("Ставка выиграла")
    money += s*2
else:
    print("Ставка проиграла!")

print("Ваш баланс: "+ money)
```

UPD: добавил `money += s*2`

Comment: Благодарю. Еще такой вопрос, я изменил вопрос, там написано немного подругому, посмотри пожалуйста. Всегда выполняется 1 условие. Почему???

Comment: В коде ТСа есть `money += s*2`, а здесь только `money += s*5`, с отступами тоже всё нормально вроде

Comment: У тебя первое уловие - строгое сравнение. Хочешь сказать, что у тебя random каждый раз выдаёт 0? Выведи значения `v` и `r` перед условием в консоль и посмотри, что из себя они представляют.

Comment: У тебя в коде `print("1")` на каждое условие.

Comment: @dIm0n, да, добавил x2

Comment: Ну так при проигрыше не должно выдаваться никакое вроде, разве нет?

Comment: @КириллВеликий зависит от того, насколько ты действительно учитываешь это, говоря "условие не работает". Особенно, когда речь идет о рандоме. Нужно самому себе давать понять, по какой ветви пошла программа. А как это для пользователя выводить и что он должен видеть в этих ситуациях, решаешь ты сам.

Comment: Ну вот тут 3 условия. При выигрыше выполняется 1 из 3 и все, при не совпадениях по факту они просто должны пропускаться, или тут не так?